# Exactly how do I make a resizing cross-domain iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, cross-domain

I am a complete beginner web it comes to web development which is why I can't actually implement any of the solutions I have found so far.

I essentially wish to display content from one of my sites on another. Please assume for now that this second/host site is a local html page and the first/parent(is this right?) site is http://www.mydomain.com

My only other requirement is that the solution should work on Chrome and preferably other modern browsers.

Thanks in advance.

--EDIT--
By resizing iFrame I mean that I want an iFrame that will either:
i) automatically set itself to the browser's size (actual usable space not window itself) + refreshes every 1 second
ii) change its height based on content being accessed from a different domain

Comment: Please explain what you mean by _a resizing cross-domain iFrame_.

Comment: I have already googled it thank you very much. What I do not understand is where to use the code or how to do so. For example I tried using jQuery to get the actual size of the document space but could not pass the variable.